# Application error

Tags: debugging, application-error

HI,
  I'm getting following error when I run the application after building it. Any solution to this problem is appreciated.

"The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000022). Click on OK to terminate the application."

Thanks in adv..

Comment: Please specify the environment/language in the question/tags. Is it .net/winforms?

Comment: I searched in google and there are lots of solutions suggested to set the Permissions etc. but nothing is working for me.

Comment: Read the first comment, what is the environment? the development language? What is the application doing? Have you tried debugging? Is this a programming question? have you developed the application?

Comment: Application is developed on Visual studio 2004, native c++.
It is a programming (debugging) question. I can't attach debugger or start with a debugger due to this error. I think windows failed to launch or load the application.

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause of this error seems to be an inability to find a required DLL file. As you noted, this is often due to permission problems, but perhaps in your case you are dependent upon a DLL not in your path.

Comment: In dependency viewer it shows all the dependent dlls, but DWMAPI.dll not found & MPR.dll not properly loaded (miss-match with WNetRestoreCount), but they are delayload dlls.
Do you think this might be an issue? Till yesterday I don't have any issue, from today this is the problem. :-(

Comment: What changed between yesterday and today? -- I think DWMAPI.dll and MPR.dll are probably red-herrings; as you say, they should be delay loaded. Have you checked the permissions on all the other dependent DLLs?

Comment: I reinstalled the application with latest build, problem is no more seen. Dependency viewer still shows previously mentioned mismatches (delayload dlls).

I wonder what kind of dependency causing this problem in the first place. I have seen this problem couple of times and some how it goes of without giving a clue of route cause.